# mongodb command line automatically getting closed

Tags: mongodb

I am facing problem with mongo shell(commandline) from morning, til yesterday it worked fine. After my system reboot(windows7 32 bit), I double-clicked on mongod, it appears and closes automatically with in fraction of seconds, the same happened for mongo also.

I tried opening it with administrator privilege but no use it closes automatically

any help will be appreciated

Comment: mongod is not mongo shell, it is mongo db engine. You should use mongo to open shell. Try to open console(cmd) at first and then execute commands there. In this case you would have more information in case of issues.

Comment: thanks for your response, but when i open mongo also it automatically getting closed in seconds

Comment: Use console, then you would see what is the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple thing is to delete my `mongod.lock` file

after deleting it everything going smooth

Comment: ```mongo.lock``` file can be found in ```C:\data\db``` folder.